# How to add this dependencies in plugin

Tags: android-studio, dependencies

How to add this Class path in plugin

I'm using the Android dolphin and where these class Path is adding as a plugin, I tried to add like this id '**com.github.dcendents.android-maven**' version '1.5', getting the error 'Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider'.
'

Comment: Add this to youe dependency block -> `implementation 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'` and add this line to